# Apache Default Virtual Host not loaded in right order

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, centos7

Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

For a while now, I've had a catchall page setup for my Apache server so bots would not crawl my main site unless they had my domain name.

Recently however, I noticed this no longer works with my config. When loading the page by IP address (let's say 10.20.20.10), I get the main site (let's say mysite.net) instead of the catchall.

The config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerName default
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName default
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:80>
        ServerName mysite.net
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:443>
        ServerName mysite.net
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Running `apachectl -S` revealed to me that it is not being loaded as the default:

```
10.20.20.10:443       is a NameVirtualHost
     default server mysite.net (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/01-mysite.conf:24)
     port 443 namevhost mysite.net (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/01-mysite.conf:24)
*:80                   localhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/00-catchall.conf:2)
*:443                  localhost (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/00-catchall.conf:16)
```

I was able to find a way to have my catchall load by default, but it required that I changed my catchall to the same listen IP as my main virtual host. Not the most ideal solution. I'd imagine changing all vhosts to * would also do it, but that's not ideal either.

Based on observation, it appeared like httpd prefers a closer match and takes an IP match over "*". Can anyone shed light on why Apache does not load the first vhost and what might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering here, doesn't it make sense that since `mysite.net` is the first vhost for `VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:80` that it would become the default site?

I have no idea why `_default_` isn't working for you. But maybe something like this could work instead. Is this what you say you've tried already? What's not ideal about it?

```
<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:80>
        ServerName default
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:443>
        ServerName default
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:80>
        ServerName mysite.net
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.20.20.10:443>
        ServerName mysite.net
        # More config ...
</VirtualHost>
```

**This question/answer would explain your problem if you were using Apache 2.2. But you're not.** Honestly it's not something I'm overly familiar with. Apparently, you're not supposed to use `_default_` with name based virtual hosting, rather `*:*` or `*:port`.

[difference between _default_:* and *:* in VirtualHost Context](https://serverfault.com/questions/567320/difference-between-default-and-in-virtualhost-context)

```
So with a named based virtualhosting configuration:

<Virtualhost *:80> with ServerName foo.com means "on all IPs managed on this host", "on port 80", "if the request host header is foo.com" I'll use this virtualhost
<Virtualhost *:*> with Servername foo.com means "on all IPs managed on this host", "on all ports", "if the request host header is foo.com" I'll use this virtualhost
<Virtualhost 10.0.0.2:*> with Servername foo.com means "for request incoming from my network interface 10.0.0.2", "on all ports", "if the request host header is foo.com" I'll use this virtualhost
<Virtualhost _default_:*> with Servername foo.com : should not be used with name based virtualhosting
And on an IP based Virtualhosting:

<Virtualhost 10.0.0.2:*> means "I'll use this virtualhost for request coming on my 10.0.0.2 interface"
<Virtualhost _default_:443> means "I'll use this virtualhost for all other network interface on my host for request coming on port 443"
<Virtualhost _default_:*> means "I'll use this virtualhost for all other network interface on my host, if it is not matched by a previous rule, and if the request host header is not matched by a named based virtualhost"
```

**Ubuntu same as you** I tried assigning an IP to one of the vhosts (example2.com) rather than `<VirtualHost *:80>` and it now overrides the default vhost. Seems this is just how Apache works. A * cannot override an IP address. `curl 192.168.1.143` now gives me example2.com instead of the catchall page.

```
$ sudo apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.1.143:80       example2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example2.com.conf:1)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www1.swass (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www1.swass (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
                 wild alias *.example.com
```

Best of luck

Comment: Funny, I was actually using `*` before then switched to `_default_` since it was more symbolic. In both cases though the same result happened. As you said, I feel Apache is treating mysite.net as the first vhost for 10.20.20.10.

Comment: @Datus I'm gonna test this

Comment: @Datus I use Ubuntu. Each vhost is in a separate file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. There's a file called `000-default.conf` that contains the catchall default site. It gets loaded when I connect via IP (verified). Each vhost is defined with `<VirtualHost *:80>`. I'm assuming `000-default.conf` loads first due to it's filename and that's the only reason it's default. It's `Apache 2.4.18`. Does any of this help you?

Comment: Appreciate your help on this. The load order should be correct with `00-catchall.conf` being my desired default and `01-insertsite.conf` being my main site. For the sake of trying things I included the file explicitly in the main `httpd.conf` with the same effect.

I'm running this on a CentOS 7 host. The structure looks like Ubuntu on my server because I liked how they organized it. ;-)

Comment: @Datus My apache behaves the same as yours. Once I gave an IP address to one of the vhosts, it overrode the default host...

Comment: Oh sorry, misread there. Definitely strange because I feel like 2 months ago I was showing a friend this configuration and it was working. My only other thought is maybe I should dig through the patch notes.

Comment: @Things happen :). I've updated my answer at the bottom so you can see the output of `apachectl -S`.

Comment: It blows my mind. It is getting a bit late over here, but I will need to do a full dive into my config tomorrow and see what's up in my config.  Again, I appreciate the help on this :-)